# Loop in BufferManagerWriteGrow.overflow

Tags: java, rmi

When you invoke a method @Remote (remote.call (objects);) and I carry the list objects, sometimes this process loops and does not close, I noticed that this occurs when I transport large objects, which I would have to adjust to it functions normally

```
@LocalBean
Class ProcessBean {

    @EJB
    CallerBeanRemote remote;

    @EJB
    Dao dao;

    public void process() {
         List objects = dao.findAll();
         remote.call(objects);
    }
}

@Remote
Interface CallerBeanRemote {
     void call(List objects);
}

@LocalBean
Class CallerBean implements CallerBeanRemote {

   public void call(List objects) {
        //process
   }       

}
```

Stacktrace

```
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.BufferManagerWriteGrow.overflow(BufferManagerWriteGrow.java:73)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_2.grow(CDROutputStream_1_2.java:266)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_2.alignAndReserve(CDROutputStream_1_2.java:229)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.internalWriteOctetArray(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:454)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_octet_array(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:470)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_octet_array(CDROutputObject.java:435)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.write_value(TypeCodeImpl.java:1661)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_TypeCode(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:504)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:488)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:468)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:365)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:743)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:565)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:506)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:776)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:551)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:523)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:492)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashMap.internalWriteEntries(HashMap.java:1776)
at java.util.HashMap.writeObject(HashMap.java:1354)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor642.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:647)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:613)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:500)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TCUtility.marshalIn(TCUtility.java:157)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:611)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:489)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:468)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:365)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:743)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:565)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:506)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:776)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:551)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:523)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:492)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.HashSet.writeObject(HashSet.java:287)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor640.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:647)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:613)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:565)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:506)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:776)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:551)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_abstract_interface(CDROutputObject.java:523)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAbstractObject(Util.java:492)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectOverride(IIOPOutputStream.java:177)
at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:344)
at java.util.ArrayList.writeObject(ArrayList.java:762)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor177.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.invokeObjectWriter(IIOPOutputStream.java:647)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:613)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:500)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TCUtility.marshalIn(TCUtility.java:157)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:611)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:489)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:468)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:365)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:743)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:565)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:506)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.writeObjectField(IIOPOutputStream.java:776)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputClassFields(IIOPOutputStream.java:847)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.defaultWriteObjectDelegate(IIOPOutputStream.java:246)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.outputObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:615)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPOutputStream.simpleWriteObject(IIOPOutputStream.java:197)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:234)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValueWithVersion(ValueHandlerImpl.java:215)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.writeValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:179)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.callWriteValue(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:711)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.writeRMIIIOPValueType(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:696)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:821)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_value(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:834)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_value(CDROutputObject.java:500)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.TCUtility.marshalIn(TCUtility.java:157)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.corba.AnyImpl.write_value(AnyImpl.java:611)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputStream_1_0.write_any(CDROutputStream_1_0.java:489)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDROutputObject.write_any(CDROutputObject.java:468)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.writeAny(Util.java:365)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$10.write(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:306)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.writeArguments(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:465)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:196)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:150)
at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:226)
at br.com.acessorio.ejb.business.facade.__CallerBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.call(br/com/acessorio/ejb/business/facade/__CallerBeanRemote_Remote_DynamicStub.java
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow.  Please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question so that people have enough information to help.

Comment: And please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: And how does throwing an exception equate to looping?

Comment: This is no exception, is a thread dump extracted by VisualVM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after much searching I noticed that glassfish exchange native parameter

```
com.sun.CORBA.encoding.ORBEnableJavaSerialization=true
```

per

```
com.sun.corba.ee.encoding.ORBEnableJavaSerialization=true
```

due to this JSG did not work and the CDR took

Answer (score 0):

performing the debug class below that detected the value passed the first time for newlength is 1073741824 then there is a multiplication by 2 bringing a negative value -2147483648 then it starts while {} and never ends

```
public class BufferManagerWriteGrow extends BufferManagerWrite

protected ByteBuffer overflow(ByteBuffer byteBuffer, int numBytesNeeded) {
70      int newLength = byteBuffer.limit() * 2; //1073741824 * 2 = -2147483648
        // byteBuffer actual size java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=1073741824 lim=1073741824 cap=1073741824]
72      while (byteBuffer.position() + numBytesNeeded >= newLength) {
73        newLength *= 2;
        }
75      ByteBufferPool byteBufferPool = this.orb.getByteBufferPool();
76      ByteBuffer newBB = byteBufferPool.getByteBuffer(newLength);

78      byteBuffer.flip();
79      newBB.put(byteBuffer);

81      byteBufferPool.releaseByteBuffer(byteBuffer);
82      return newBB;
}
```

Where can i configure byteBuffer.limit() value?